# How do I write a command line application in Ruby with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Any idea how to write command line application in ruby with rspec ?

How to test drive a command Application.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, RSpec is a testing framework, not something you use to literally write your application with.

Comment: so what is testdriven about it ..?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to ask there either, sorry.

Comment: i am running my program and it works but every time i run it, i use rspec myprogram_spec.rb, cant i run the program directly using ruby myprogram.rb, what should i modify in my code. ?

Comment: Running the spec file should only be running the tests. Your program should run just fine on its own if you deleted all the test code; if it doesn't you've done something wrong.

Comment: I have all my @newbook = Book.new kinda code in spec file and i am requiring book.rb into book_spec.rb the book.rb naturally wont run ...

Comment: Then you haven't written a command line application at all, and your question has nothing to do with RSpec.

Comment: man you are not helping, thats what my question was how to write with rspec... whatever i have written

Comment: That's because you haven't given enough information and you haven't given it clearly enough for me to even know what you're asking.

Comment: I think the OP needs to think out what is trying to be accomplished, and rewrite the question more clearly. As is, what is being asked isn't clear and needs to be restated. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba), which allows you to drive command-line app development using Cucumber, which, under the covers, uses RSpec.  It handles executing programs and capturing their output and exit status, which can be kindof a pain to do on your own.  As an example:

```
Given the file "foo.txt" exists
When I successfully execute `cp foo.txt bar.txt`
Then a file named "bar.txt" should exist
And the file "bar.txt" should the same contents as "foo.txt"
```

Aruba provides you the second and third steps, you provide the others:

```
CONTENTS = 'some contents'

Given /^the file "([^"]*)" exists$/ do |file|
  File.open(file,'w') { |file| file.puts(CONTENTS) }
end
Then /^the file "([^"]*)" should the same contents as "([^"]*)"$/ do |dest_file,source_file|
  contents = File.read(dest_file)
  contents.should == CONTENTS
end
```

There's a lot more tricky stuff to testing command-line apps, but aruba is a big help

Comment: May be my question was not put up properly but this is what i was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run a command you can use backticks around the command and have a String returned:

```
`ruby /path/to/my_command.rb arg1 arg2`.should == "something"
```

But I personally would limit this style of testing to a very limited subset of your tests.  These are integration tests, more than unit tests, which doesn't mean you shouldn't write them, but you should probably test at a slightly lower level first.

Being able to test your command at a lower level, however, requires structuring it in a way that is easy to pull individual units from.  If your script is a big procedural script, then you probably can't do much, but if it's composed of Classes that represent the various commands it will run, you can test those classes without executing the command in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Watch Ryan Bigg's [pilot screencast](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/10/screencast-pilot/) which gives some good tips on test driving a vanilla ruby app